# How to get the address the sender sent bitcoin to

Tags: java, bitcoin

Basicly, I'm building a server which has a bitcoin wallet with many receive addresses. The addresses can be linked to different clients.

If you send coins to any address they are gonna end up into the servers wallet.

The question is, how do I know what was the address the bitcoin sender sent the coins?

I'm using BitconJ. The server is written in Java.

Comment: Can you share some code please ?

Comment: Are you looking for the address that received the coins or are you trying to figure out what the sending address of the transaction was? In the latter case you may have multiple addresses (or even scripts that are not addresses at all).

Comment: I want the address the sender entered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself. This is my code for figuring out to which address the amount was sent to.

```
                @Override
                public void onCoinsReceived(Wallet wallet, Transaction tx, Coin prevBalance, Coin newBalance) {
                    System.out.println("Received a transaction.");
                    for (int i = 0; i < tx.getOutputs().size(); i++) {
                        for (ECKey addr : wallet().getImportedKeys()) {
                            Address expectedAddr = addr.toAddress(Main.PARAMS);
                            for (int j = 0; j < tx.getOutputs().size(); j++) 
                                String incoming = tx.getOutputs().get(i).getAddressFromP2PKHScript(Main.PARAMS)
                                        .toBase58();
                                if (incoming.equals(expectedAddr)){
                                 // Enter your code here
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

You might notice that I actually need to know what I'm looking for in the transaction outputs.